# publishing .sqlproj database project

Tags: sqlproj

I'm trying to build a .sqlproj database project and I'm getting the following error:

The "SqlServerVerification" parameter is not supported by the "SqlBuildTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property

my .sqlproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <Name>Ilumno.CSU.DB</Name>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectVersion>4.1</ProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{3f451615-f8c4-4f70-936f-bbaa27382c62}</ProjectGuid>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql110DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    <OutputType>Database</OutputType>
    <RootPath>
    </RootPath>
    <RootNamespace>Ilumno.CSU.DB</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Ilumno.CSU.DB</AssemblyName>
    <ModelCollation>1033, CI</ModelCollation>
    <DefaultFileStructure>BySchemaAndSchemaType</DefaultFileStructure>
    <DeployToDatabase>True</DeployToDatabase>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetLanguage>CS</TargetLanguage>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <SqlServerVerification>False</SqlServerVerification>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseSet>True</TargetDatabaseSet>
    <TargetDatabase>Ilumno.CSU.DB</TargetDatabase>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '199|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DEMO|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '231|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '208|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '206|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '239|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '234|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '253|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '138|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '265|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '267|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '339|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '233|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '404|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'PROD|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '419|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '425|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '257|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '299|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '306|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '258|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '426|AnyCPU' ">
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
    <Folder Include="Scripts" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="Roles.sql" />
    <Build Include="RoleNames.sql" />
    <Build Include="Languages.sql" />
    <Build Include="Users.sql" />
    <Build Include="Universities.sql" />
    <Build Include="UniversityLegalRepresentatives.sql" />
    <Build Include="UsersUniversities.sql" />
    <Build Include="Cities.sql" />
    <Build Include="Permissions.sql" />
    <Build Include="PermissionsRoles.sql" />
    <Build Include="Provinces.sql" />
    <Build Include="Countries.sql" />
    <Build Include="Periods.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertCities.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertCountries.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertProvinces.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUs.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSULegalRepresentatives.sql" />
    <Build Include="UsersCSUs.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUTypes.sql" />
    <Build Include="Informations.sql" />
    <Build Include="vwIlumnoUsersUniversities.sql" />
    <Build Include="vwIlumnoUsersCSUs.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUsInformations.sql" />
    <Build Include="UniversitiesInformations.sql" />
    <Build Include="InformationTemplates.sql" />
    <Build Include="Events.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUsEvents.sql" />
    <Build Include="UniversitiesEvents.sql" />
    <Build Include="Indicators.sql" />
    <Build Include="IndicatorGroups.sql" />
    <Build Include="Objectives.sql" />
    <Build Include="ObjectiveDetails.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUMaturityGrades.sql" />
    <Build Include="Currencies.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUAuditoryStatus.sql" />
    <Build Include="IssueTypes.sql" />
    <Build Include="Issues.sql" />
    <Build Include="IssueDetails.sql" />
    <Build Include="Auditories.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryItemTypes.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryPredefinedItems.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryItems.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUOpeningDateTimes.sql" />
    <Build Include="WeekDays.sql" />
    <Build Include="UniversityImages.sql" />
    <Build Include="CSUImages.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryStatuses.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryItemObservationImprovements.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryTemplates.sql" />
    <Build Include="AuditoryTemplateItems.sql" />
    <Build Include="Advertisements.sql" />
    <Build Include="AdvertisementStatuses.sql" />
    <Build Include="AdvertisementFiles.sql" />
    <Build Include="AdvertisementEvaluations.sql" />
    <Build Include="EventTypes.sql" />
    <None Include="Script.PostDeployment.FirstDeployOnly.PROD.sql" />
    <Build Include="FavouriteIndicators.sql" />
    <Build Include="FavouriteIndicatorRoles.sql" />
    <Build Include="FavouriteIndicatorParams.sql" />
    <Build Include="ObjectiveWeekDetails.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PostDeploy Include="Script.PostDeployment.TEST.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Ilumno.CSU.API.DB.publish.xml" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertPermissionsByRole.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertIndicators.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertAuditoryTemplateTypesAndPredefinedItems.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertUniversitiesAndCSUsPROD.AREAANDINA.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\UniversitiesAndCSUImporter.sql" />
    <None Include="Script.PostDeployment.PROD.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertUniversitiesAndCSUsPROD.SIGLO21.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertUniversitiesAndCSUsPROD.POLITECNICO.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\DropConstraints.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\AddConstraints.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\InsertUniversitiesAndCSUsPROD.UNIJORGE.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <RefactorLog Include="Ilumno.CSU.DB.refactorlog" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetDatabaseName)' != '' Or '$(TargetConnectionString)' != ''">
  <TargetConnectionStringXml Condition="'$(TargetConnectionString)' != ''">
    &lt;TargetConnectionString xdt:Transform="Replace"&gt;$(TargetConnectionString)&lt;/TargetConnectionString&gt;
  </TargetConnectionStringXml>
  <TargetDatabaseXml Condition="'$(TargetDatabaseName)' != ''">
    &lt;TargetDatabaseName xdt:Transform="Replace"&gt;$(TargetDatabaseName)&lt;/TargetDatabaseName&gt;
  </TargetDatabaseXml>
  <TransformPublishXml>
      &lt;Project xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"&gt;
      &lt;PropertyGroup&gt;$(TargetConnectionStringXml)$(TargetDatabaseXml)&lt;/PropertyGroup&gt;
      &lt;/Project&gt;
  </TransformPublishXml>
  <SqlPublishProfilePath Condition="'$([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($(SqlPublishProfilePath)))' == 'False'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(SqlPublishProfilePath)</SqlPublishProfilePath>
  <!-- In order to do a transform, we HAVE to change the SqlPublishProfilePath -->
  <TransformOutputFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Transformed_$(TargetDatabaseName).publish.xml</TransformOutputFile>
  <TransformScope>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</TransformScope>
  <TransformStackTraceEnabled Condition="'$(TransformStackTraceEnabled)'==''">False</TransformStackTraceEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
<UsingTask TaskName="ParameterizeTransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="BeforePublish" Condition="'$(TargetDatabaseName)' != '' Or '$(TargetConnectionString)' != ''">
  <Message Text="TargetDatabaseName = '$(TargetDatabaseName)', TargetConnectionString = '$(TargetConnectionString)', PublishScriptFileName = '$(PublishScriptFileName)', Transformed Sql Publish Profile Path = '$(TransformOutputFile)'" Importance="high" />
  <!-- If TargetDatabaseName or TargetConnectionString, is passed in then we use the tokenize transform to create a parameterized sql publish file -->
  <Error Condition="!Exists($(SqlPublishProfilePath))" Text="The SqlPublishProfilePath '$(SqlPublishProfilePath)' does not exist, please specify a valid file using msbuild /p:SqlPublishProfilePath='Path'" />
  <ParameterizeTransformXml Source="$(SqlPublishProfilePath)" IsSourceAFile="True" Transform="$(TransformPublishXml)" IsTransformAFile="False" Destination="$(TransformOutputFile)" IsDestinationAFile="True" Scope="$(TransformScope)" StackTrace="$(TransformStackTraceEnabled)" SourceRootPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SqlPublishProfilePath>$(TransformOutputFile)</SqlPublishProfilePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error and resolved it by having it use a VisualStudioVersion of 12.0 instead of 11.0.

11.0
    
    True
    11.0